# Apache logs by day

Tags: apache, logging

I'm working with Apache and JBoss. The latter's way to keep logs is quite fine in the sense it keeps (when chosen in log4j) logs of the same day in the same file. This makes logs, backups and statistics more manageable.

Is that possible to be achieved in Apache? One log file per day with all info of that day only in that file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's lots of ways of doing this - mostly dependant on which OS this is running on - you didn't say.

You can run an external program like [logrotate](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/117) which moves the files around and tells apache to flush/close/reopen its file handles.

Alternatively, Apache httpd comes with a utility called [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html) which is usually configured as a log output filter.

Comment: Thanks, I am already using logrotate with dateext, generating files of previous 24 hours, with info of two different days in each file, what is what I want to avoid. You mean there is an approach for the feature I am requesting in logrotate?

Comment: Click through to the Apache's `rotatelogs` docs and you will see it has the ability to datestamp filenames, and to specify timezone offset or localtime. combine the two and you should be happy.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this

```
awk '{print $4}' example.log | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c
```